# Duplicate class android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelStoreOwner

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle

я добавил TabbedActivity и теперь мой проект не работает. При билде приложения я получаю такую ошибку

```
Duplicate class android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelStoreOwner found in modules classes.jar (android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0-beta1) and classes.jar (android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.1)
```

и еще пару десятков с похожим контекстом, как ее пофиксить в интернете информации не нашел мой

build.gradle(app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

check.dependsOn 'assembleDebugAndroidTest'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
flavorDimensions "minSdkVersion"

defaultConfig {

    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
 'android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility 1.8
    targetCompatibility 1.8
}
}

configurations.all {
resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
}


dependencies {
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'

implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'


implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.2.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.1.0'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.3.3'
implementation 'com.yanzhenjie.zbar:camera:1.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.19.0'
testImplementation "org.robolectric:robolectric:3.2.2"
 }


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

build.gradle(project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to 
all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    google()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

}
}

 allprojects {
 repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    google()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
}
apply plugin: 'checkstyle'
apply plugin: 'pmd'

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
task pmd(type: Pmd) {
ruleSetFiles = files("${project.rootDir}/pmd.xml")
ruleSets = ["java-basic", "java-braces", "java-strings"]

source 'src'
include '**/*.java'
exclude '**/gen/**'
}
 task checkstyle(type: Checkstyle) {
configFile rootProject.file('checkstyle.xml')
source 'src'
include '**/*.java'
exclude '**/gen/**'

classpath = files()
}

pmd {
consoleOutput = true
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В build.gradle(app) в `dependencies {`
добавить `implementation ('android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1')`